# Theme my Login:error al entrar al admin

Tags: wordpress

estoy arrancando con wordpress, ya pude hacer un par de cosas no muy complejas. Ahora lo que hice fue instalar Theme my login 7.0.7 en un worpress 4.9.6.
Primero me di cuenta que en el admin no aparecian las opciones como se veian en el tutorial que estaba haciendo, y ahora ni si queira puedo entrar al admin, me da error, alguien sabe que puede ser? gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más seguro es que se haya cambiado el nombre de la carpeta. Prueba a checkear los directorios de la instalación y ver si existe la carpeta wp-admin.

Comment: era el pluguin, parece q tiene un bug o algo, le cambie el nombre a la carpeta del plugin y me pude loguear ;)